# Searching for a better method/framework/anything to build deb packages

Tags: package-management, deb, canonical, usability

**For those that have downvoted, if you care to let me know why, I can try to improve the question.**

I have been scouring the pipes for an official page on an officially sanctioned method of building .deb packages for Ubuntu.  I want a method that is maintainable and can be relatively easily updated to work for new Ubuntu releases, hence the "official" keyword.

I agree with the commenter that perhaps it's difficult to have a single method, but there has to be a reasonable framework from within people can build packages for different purposes.  I don't even see such a framework.  I see fragmentation and competing methods.  I can hardly imagine that this is ideal.  (Yes, this paragraph is a rant.  I cannot help it!)

Comment: Although I understand what you are saying, it is more like a statement than a question. Part of the issue is that there are numerous reasons to create a `.deb` file, numerous tools, numerous different needs, numerous ways to do the job. However, The question is not really clear as it is I think.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I have tried to rephrase my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **Debian** check:

- [Debian New Maintainers' Guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/index.en.html)
- [Debian Packaging Tutorial](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/packaging-tutorial/packaging-tutorial.en.pdf)

For **Ubuntu**:

- [UbuntuDevelopment -> Packaging](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment#Packaging-1)

From that ↑↑ page:

> All Ubuntu developers should be familiar with the Debian New
>   Maintainer Guide; though be aware that there are many differences
>   (technical, social and procedural) between Ubuntu and Debian of which
>   they must also be aware.

And also:

- [The Ubuntu Packaging Guide](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/)

Comment: After searching around for a better solution, I decided that Josue's answer is as good as there is so I thank him for his help.